# Is it possible to add custom TestNG xml tags

Tags: testng

Is it possible to add custom TestNG xml tags inside TestNG xml like following code snippet.I just wanted to put some meta data of the files.

**Custom TestNG xml tags**

```
<description>
        <title>My sample file</title>
        <author>Sam</author>
</description>

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

 <description>
    <title>My sample file</title>
    <author>Sam</author>
  </description>

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Nopackage" >
    <classes>
       <class name="NoPackageTest" />
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Regression1">
    <classes>
      <class name="test.sample.ParameterSample"/>
      <class name="test.sample.ParameterTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

If can not add custom TestNG xml tags please letme know how can i put description in TestNG XML file.

Comment: What are you trying to do and why? You should have a look at how xml validation (dtd and xsd) is working.

Comment: @JulienHerr i just wanted to add a new xml custom tag.This tag is not part of the TestNG execution.it is for internal meta data purposes.I added and but xml is not valid but even can execute with custom tags.

Comment: I don't recommand it and it won't work when testng will use xsd instead of dtd

Comment: @JulienHerr yea for best practice i moved meta data into parameters.Thanks

Comment: Other solutions could be to use XML comments (but could be difficult to parse) or  to use a filename convention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very strange because you are not supposed to break xml validation (in fact, it is often not possible :p)

BTW, a XML valid alternative could be:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">
  <parameter name="title" value="My sample file"/>
  <parameter name="author" value="Sam"/>
  <test name="Nopackage">
    <classes>
       <class name="NoPackageTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Regression1">
    <classes>
      <class name="test.sample.ParameterSample"/>
      <class name="test.sample.ParameterTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```